# EFI fuse blows randomly.

Tags: electrical, toyota, fuel-system, fuse, rav4

I am beating my head in with this issue. EFI fuse blows randomly, I have found no patter. When it blow, it will keep blowing them and not start. I have to disconnect the battery first and then replace the fuse. Then it will run a good while till it blow the fuse again. Looking for a short but I can't find one but the battery thing makes me think it is something deeper. I am trying to track down the short right now but since it is operating normally it is fine. Guess I have to wait till it blows and get it home like that to figure it out. However the car works normal just does that randomly.

1996 Toyota Rav4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are several EFI components protected by that fuse and any one of them can cause the fuse to blow, my bet is on the fuel pump needs replaced as it draws the most current and will draw more current as it ages.

One other thing can cause it is a short to ground in the wiring, which is rare.

1. Fuel Pump
2. IAC valve
3. EGR valve
4. Vapor pressure Sensor
5. Evap Solenoid
6. ECM

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would putting a fuse with a higher amps be better? Any way of diagnosing to see if the fuel pump does draw more current? It has 250k miles on it. I guess I would have to wait for the fuse to blow and diagnose then.

Comment: Also does disconnecting the battery reset something with the current the old fuel pump draws? Thanks

Comment: "Would putting a fuse with a higher amps be better?" Bad idea, the fuse protects the wiring, larger fuse you risk damaging the wire. "does disconnecting the battery reset something with the current the old fuel pump draws? " No.

Comment: Hmm just find it super odd that disconnecting the battery is the only way to get it to stop popping the fuse. Seems like something has to reset in the system for it go back to normal.

Comment: My bet is still on the fuel pump.

Comment: Well the fuse blew yesterday and keeps blowing now. A battery disconnect doesn't help it. I am going to disconnect the fuel pump and see if the fuse keeps popping.

Comment: I replaced the fuel pump with a new one. Still have the same issue. However I noticed that I don't have to disconnect the battery. I just have to replace the fuse and disconnect then reconnect the wiring to the fuel pump to get it to go again.

Answer (score 0):

It was a short somewhere with the O2 sensors. It would blow randomly because it was the ECU was trying to read them and the short blew the fuse. I disconnected them and the car worked fine.

Comment: sounds like a wiring harness issue.  The harness to the injectors is the same harness as the o2 sensor.  Our van had a short in that harness.  Has your gas mileage suffered?